# How can pointers improve program efficiency?

Tags: c, pointers

In C I have noted that pointers result in faster program execution. How is it possible, as it must fetch the pointer variable before going to the actual variable?

Comment: Do you mean that you have witnessed a pointerless C program?

Comment: I'm guessing this  may mean passing pointers to data structures instead of the entire data structure.

Answer (score 3):

Pointers don't result in faster program execution. Smart algorithms result in faster program execution. Sometimes algorithms can be made smarter by using pointers in the right way. Pointers are never a magic wand to throw at problems to make the solutions faster.

Pointers are just a design paradigm though, using functional programming you do not use any pointers at all.

Comment: Nit: One doesn't even use pointers in a "non functional" language like Java or Python. The only modern language I know of that doesn't have a "null-value" is Haskell - but that's a different topic.

Comment: @pst Did I say that functional programming is the only place you don't use pointers?

Comment: It is a vague and misleading statement at best, hence the "nit".

Comment: @pst Well you can call it references if you like but a pointer stays a pointer though ;-)

Comment: @junix No, they are different. Some languages, like ECMAScript, *don't even have "references"* (per the specification) and yet they still have Call By Object Sharing semantics.

Answer (score 1):

This is not true. The reason for faster program execution is not the availablility of pointers. It's a question of what you do with the pointers. The (possibly) faster program execution yields from the fact that no hidden functionality is introduced with C.

Take a string for example. Common implementations in other languages introduce a length field along with the string in order to keep track of the length of the string. This "bookkeeping" (although hidden from the programmer) causes extra cycles to be executed.

Another example is the fact that C does not check if the pointer you are dereferencing is valid or not. This evaluation would also cost extra cycles.

Answer (score 0):

The C standard does not specify any required speed, so it doesn't make sense to attribute speed to features of C. Consider that some C implementations produce more optimal machine code than others, and it might make more sense to attribute speed to aspects of specific implementations of C<sub>1</sub>. Don't confuse implementation and specification.

<sub>1:  To make a meaningful comparison of the speed of specific implementations of C, you'd probably want to mention your OS (major and minor version), your compiler (major and minor version), your CPU (model), mainboard, memory (model and configuration) and the command line arguments you used.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

While I am aware every answer to the question come from people far more knowledgeable than me in C (and I am out of my league actually), IMVHO and/or limited knowledge, pointers *do* improve efficiency.

To answer the OP's question (and ignoring the rest about program execution and fetching):

> How can pointers improve program efficiency?

By avoiding duplication of data. Although this efficiency may only be notable when dealing with user-defined variables, "structures".

Here is a nice read I found on C pointers: [Why C has Pointers](http://duramecho.com/ComputerInformation/WhyCPointers.html)